# Windows 8.1 Preview keeps waking up the computer

Tags: sleep, wake-up, windows-8.1-preview

I have Windows 8.1 Preview installed, and I prefer not to power my computer down but instead put it on sleep. However, I always have to make it sleep twice. The first time I click 'sleep', the computer will go to sleep mode, and after a minute or so, it will wake up. The second time will keep it sleeping, though, but this sure is annoying.

I've checked all the devices and none of them are allowed to wake the computer. I've also checked 'powercfg -lastwake' after the first sleep, but it returns nothing.

Is this just a 'feature' of Win8(.1), or what could be the cause of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If this behavior only occurs in the preview then it's probably a bug. I had a myriad of those when using the latest preview. Plenty of things that worked in 8 are broken in the 8.1 preview. The RTM had all the bugs I encountered fixed, so I'd suggest getting that one. Unless this bug carried over to the final version, I wouldn't waste time on trying to fix a buggy temp version.

Comment: The RTM has not been released yet.  So while this answer is indeed helpful and correct, until the release, it should be note this fact.

Comment: Indeed. May be the OP can get access to it through official channels. After all, a select few actually have gotten it. Until then, the message is to not take preview bugs too seriously. I experienced massive system breaking bugs in the preview so often that I actually feared they'd carry over to the RTM. I also wasted a lot of time trying to fix or circumvent them which basically never worked, yet the RTM worked as stable and flawless as could be expected for a ready to be released software.

Comment: Windows 8.1 has not been released through ANY channels at this time.  OEMs are the only "people" who have the official unleaked handed to them by Microsoft RTM build

Comment: Yes OEMs and the world's press. So plenty of people have access to it.